# PyQt5 - link Text in label with an external condition

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals, slot

SOLVED!!

I used a Qtimer to interrupt QMainWindow each one second and call to "getStartStatus" method:

```
    self.loadingLabel = QLabel('Starting...', self)
    self.loadingLabel.setGeometry(900, 700, 400, 200)
    self.loadingLabel.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
    self.loadingLabel.setStyleSheet('color:#C7BAD0')

    self.timerStartStatus = QTimer(self)
    self.timerStartStatus.timeout.connect(self.getStartStatus)
    self.timerStartStatus.start(1000)
```

Comment: As the [documentation explains](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), `input()` returns a string. Change to `if dato == '1':`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to take out the WHILE cycle and works but works and changes the label's text once.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!

I used a Qtimer to interrupt QMainWindow each one second and call to "getStartStatus" method:

```
self.loadingLabel = QLabel('Starting...', self)
self.loadingLabel.setGeometry(900, 700, 400, 200)
self.loadingLabel.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
self.loadingLabel.setStyleSheet('color:#C7BAD0')

self.timerStartStatus = QTimer(self)
self.timerStartStatus.timeout.connect(self.getStartStatus)
self.timerStartStatus.start(1000)
```